# One-liner to call a function if it's defined, else call another function

Tags: javascript

I want to call a `callback` function if one was provided by the user, or default to a default `defaultCallback` function.

I've done it as follows:

```
function defaultCallback(x) {
  console.log('default callback ' + x)
}

function test(callback) {
  let x = 'x'

  if (callback) {
    callback(x)
  } else {
    defaultCallback(x)
  }
}
```

I feel there should be a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: you could set the default argument. `function test(callback = defaultCallback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function test(callback) {
  let x = 'x'

  (typeof callback == "function" ? callback : defaultCallback)(x);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to check the type of the argument, but just assert that it's something else than `undefined`, you can use a [default initialiser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) in your parameter:

```
function test(callback = defaultCallback) {
  let x = 'x'

  callback(x);
}
```

Comment: I think a downvote warrants an explanation in this case ??  Why downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use || operator to get callback or fallback to defaultCallback.

```
function test(callback) {
   (callback || defaultCallback)('x')
}
```

Here is a test snippet you can use to view the results in the console.

```js
function defaultCallback(x) { console.log('Used default ' + x); }

function test(callback) {
  (callback || defaultCallback)('x')
}

test(undefined);
test((y) => console.log('Used func ' + y));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function test(callback) {
  let x = 'x'

  callback ? callback(x) : defaultCallBack(x);
}
```

Comment: And why is this downvoted? Does it not work?